# Remote Desktop to a VM for a user with "Virtual Machine Administrator Login"

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-virtual-machine, administrator

I have a VM where I want to allow users with "Virtual Machine Administrator Login" role to RDP, however VM does not allow me to RDP after I assign this role to a user.

Though if I login to VM and add the user specifically to be able to remote desktop he/she can access, but I cannot do this everytime a new user with "Virtual Machine Administrator Login" is added, is there anything else (beside assigning this rule to a user) has to be done to allow user RDP?

btw, my subscription does not have a public IP due to some regulations in my group, I appreciate your help.

Each time user with this rule tries to login sees this error message:
"The connection was denied because the user account is not authorized for remote login"

[image]

Please note OS is Windows Server 2016. And after installing Azure CLI and running below command I can see that assignee has the permission but is not able to login:

az role assignment list --role "Virtual Machine Administrator Login" --assignee domain_user_login --resource-group name_of_resource_group

Also, VM is already joined to a domain but nobody from that domain can access, even with "Virtual Machine Administrator Login" rule.

Comment: by any chance if the number of concurrent users is more than 2? max of 2 concurrent admin user logins is allowed in windows.

Comment: No, nobody was logged in at the time of these tests :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This feature is for Linux VM only.** You can see more detials about Log in to a Linux virtual machine in Azure using Azure Active Directory authentication in [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/login-using-aad).

For Windows VM, you can use [Azure AD Domain service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-overview) to achieve that.

Please following the steps below:

Task1: Create the 'AAD DC Administrators' group
Task2: Create or select a virtual network for Azure AD Domain Services
Task3: Enable Azure AD Domain Services
Task4: Update DNS settings for the Azure virtual network
Task5: Enable password synchronization to AAD Domain Services for a cloud-only Azure AD tenant

After completing the tasks above, you can [join a VM to the domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-admin-guide-join-windows-vm).

Comment: VM is already joined to a domain, and "Domain Admins" have admin access, however whoever tried to login cannot access VM even though they are using their domain account to login.

Comment: Oh so Virtual Machine Administrator Login is not enabled for Windows VMs? I installed Azure CLI on the VM, and when I run below command it returns user has the role: PS> az role assignment list --role "Virtual Machine Administrator Login" --assignee <assignee> --resource-group <resource_group>

Comment: Let me confirm this again. This feature is not for windows VM. The way to let you login Windows VM via AAD accounts is using AAD DS.

Comment: I'm not sure this is clear direction as I have the same issue.  I have domain joined windows virtual machines that need to allow RDP for domain accounts that are synced to on-premise domain.  Presently the only way I can allow this access is through assigning these users to the AAD DC Administrators group, but this group gives them more security than is necessary.    Saying AAD DS should be used may be correct, but how?  GPO?  Domain Group? or RDP Services Profile?  I can say that the RD services profile option to deny access is NOT checked and our users still cannot access Azure VMs.